# Embedded Javascript for Google Blogger not working on Safari (works in Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, blogger

I initially asked this question on the Google Blogger Product Forum and it was suggested that I ask here on Stackoverflow.

I have a post containing interactive graphs built using d3.js. My javascript code for building the graph is stored on Google Drive, so is the data used in the graph. I embedded links to the Javascript file in a blogger post.

When I publish the post, everything works in Chrome and Firefox i.e. the javascript code runs and the graph is built, is visible and is interactive in Chrome and Firefox. In Safari (both Mac and IPad), the graph doesn't show up. The page is just blank.

Anybody know what is causing this and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in Safari?

Comment: I checked safari console and noticed the following error **Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.** when it tries to load the js file from Google Drive

Comment: @N.P Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16824661/933980 . Might not help much in your case as don't have control over the headers of Google Drive