# problems with Cross Origin Resource Sharing: both OSX Safari and iOS Safari fail after preflight request

Tags: ios, safari, cors

Recently I come into a trouble with CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) request on Safari, both OSX and iOS, while the same request works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. I follow [the documentation of W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) and handle preflight request on server side, my response is like:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.96:4399
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Request-Method
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CustomHeader
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 08:45:25 GMT
Origin: http://192.168.1.96:4399
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Such response works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Android Browser: a POST request is sent right after the preflight request. But on Safari, after server response the reflight request, I got such error message from console:

```
Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.
```

I inspect the preflight response from server, but find it the same as above... After searching and trying so many times, I still can't make it work :-( 
   Is there anybody that come across the problem before? Could anyone figure out what mistake I've made?
   Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you a bug in Safari that you could report at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: @sideshowbarker  Thanks very much. But interestingly and occasionally I find it works when I check the "Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions" option from the develop menu on OSX Safari! I suspect that this problem might have something to do with browser security policies, and I will continue trying to figure it out.

Comment: I think It's natural that when you disable Restrictions for Cross Origin, you can connect to the target server without any problems and it's not interesting at all because the browser intendedly uses the Restrictions for Cross Origin Resource Sharing to improve our security. So, yes, the problem has something to do with the browser absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about Safari add `origin` to OPTIONS request header `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

So to fix it you should enable this header in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in response.

PS: see similar question [CORS request not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: The OP is seeing the preflight request fail complete at the network level.  What you're referring to is an improperly configured OPTIONS response.  But he's never getting that response to begin with.

Comment: @RavenHursT no, brutto is mentioning a malformed request header, hence this is the correct answer (I just verified and it did the trick for me)