# CORS for Google Cloud Storage Bucket (e.g. Firebase Storage) not fetching text in Safari when in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, safari, cors, google-cloud-storage

I set up CORS for my Google Cloud Storage Bucket according to this:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket

and by following this article:

https://bitmovin.com/faq/how-do-i-set-up-cors-for-my-google-cloud-storage-bucket/

My web page fetches the content of .txt and .jpg files contained in my Google Cloud Storage Bucket via a jscript routine.
While the set up described above works for the web and on Safari in iOS for the .jpg files, it does not work on Safari in iOS for the .txt files.
I tend to believe there is something wrong in the CORS headers. However, I'm still not able to figure this out.
Does anybody have any idea on this?

Comment: If you access the files from within an actual iOS app there should be no need to use CORS in the first place. What precisely do you mean when you say *"on iOS"*?

Comment: You are right, I should have better elaborate. Access on iOS = Access the web page in iOS (no App involved but only Safari). Just updated my question

Comment: Also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809219/problems-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing-both-osx-safari-and-ios-safari-fail but doesn't seem to work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was just out there in the right methods to use to SET the headers:
https://docs.cancergenomicscloud.org/docs/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors
https://blogs.sap.com/2013/02/11/cors-or-how-to-make-that-damn-iphone-simulator-work/
http://excellencenodejsblog.com/handing-cors-for-your-mobile-app/