# Safari: XmlHttpRequest errors due to access control checks

Tags: web, safari, cors, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to test AutoCAD Web on Safari but see strange errors only with web inspector open. Here is the scenario:

1. Open https://web.autocad.com/?user=safari_testing and open the web inspector
2. Then reload the page twice with web inspector open.
3. You will see errors in the console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://web.autocad.com/messsages?action=peek&sourceid=6a47bf3c-4d8b-bd89-14eb-813993b8ef11 due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource
```

Does anyone encounter same issue on other websites? This only happens on Safari and only with web inspector open. And there is no issue with Chrome and Firefox. I tried to find out but couldn't figure out the reason. Please help thanks!

FYI: Tested on Safari 16.6 and Safari 17.0

Similar issue:
[Safari - XMLHttpRequest cannot load X due to access control checks. [Inspector]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789513/safari-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-x-due-to-access-control-checks-inspector?rq=2)