# api request error due to access control checks. (Using xampp on Mac)

Tags: php, reactjs, xampp

I'm trying to login to my web application (made in react) and I'm using a xampp apache server on localhost, when I try to send post request to my php file it returns this error:

`[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/project/authentication.php due to access control checks.`

my request looks like this:

```
export async function doLogin(data: LoginCredentials) {
  const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:80/project/authentication.php',
    data
  );
  return await res.data;
}
```

what can I do?

Comment: So how do you know its a 500 error, thats not mentioned in any of the errors you show

Comment: you're right @RiggsFolly, I just supposed, my bad, editing now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari 10.1: XMLHttpRequest with query parameters cannot load due to access control checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517254/safari-10-1-xmlhttprequest-with-query-parameters-cannot-load-due-to-access-cont)

Comment: @Vytas there is no accepted answer so I guess it doesn't