# Loading Local json file in Safari extension Content script failed

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, safari-extension

i have a content script injected in every page of the safari browser. The blow code is injected and loading the extension json file.

```
var url = extensionAdapter.getExtensionURL(contents/test.json);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);

    request.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
      if (event.target.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(event.target.response));
      }
      else {
        reject("Error loading " + url + ", Error: " + event.target.statusText);
      }
    });

    request.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
        reject("Network Error while loading "+url);
    });

    request.send();
```

When i ru this code It gives an error "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

Able to load json in global or Background page of the extension but i need load json file in Safari extension CS.

Comment: it will...what is your url ??

Comment: is test.json in a file:// or c:// ??

Comment: extension file. its in extension directory content/test.json

Comment: provide the full url please

Comment: the path absolute to the Safari  extension . its a safari extension local file and not a system file. we can access it using  var url  = safari.extension.baseURI + 'path'. Issue is only in Safari extension. it works on Chrome/Firefox extension.

Comment: so it is basically local file..are you using any server like php or node  etc ? or just pure html & js

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW7

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS error ..To access a physical file...other than `firefox` you need to start a server 
like

> [httpster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/)

or use chrome with security disable
or test in firefox..

here is a solution on [SO you can follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari)