# False CORS failure only in iOS mobile safari when uploading images

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, safari, ionic3, mobile-safari

I'm running into a strange error on mobile Safari with my iPhone 6 on iOS 11.3.1 and in the iOS simulator.

I have an Ionic application (PWA, not Cordova) that has been working just fine for months with a backend API built with Laravel (PHP). I have CORS configured on it and it works fine.

I've just tried to implement a new feature where I upload an image and it breaks only on mobile Safari.

I see the `OPTIONS` request go through and it looks correct. In fact, the request/response look identical except for the `User-Agent` from desktop Safari which works.

On desktop Safari this is followed up by a `POST` which succeeds.

On mobile Safari the `POST` does not even attempt to go out, instead, I get a message `Failed to load resource: Origin https://upload.geekity.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` despite the `OPTIONS` request returning `https://upload.geekity.com` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Here are screenshots of web inspector for both `OPTIONS` and `POST` on desktop and mobile safari.

[image: Desktop Safari OPTIONS]
[image: Desktop Safari POST]
[image: iOS Safari OPTIONS]
[image: iOS Safari POST]

You can look at the source here: [image-upload](https://github.com/geekitycom/image-upload).

I really have no idea what could be happening here to make this fail in this way.

Comment: Try adding "Origin" in your "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" response header in your OPTIONS response.(Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ORIGIN, AUTHORISATION) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Does it happen with smaller images?

Comment: Yes, it happens with small images as well. In fact, the request works fine if I comment out the line of code that attaches the image to the request.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't found a solution yet. We just moved on without that feature for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the CORS error message is very misleading. I've been struggling with the exact same issue for the past couple of days and it turned out the image I was trying to upload from my phone was too large for the app server I'm using which is nginx on Kubernetes; so the fix which works for me is to just add this annotation to the ingress configuration

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"

to removes any restriction on upload size.

[image: 413 Request Entity Too Large]

Answer (score 1):

for laravel-5.4.*
add following line in .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization"
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. I'm using the `barryvdh/laravel-cors` library for the API and it's set to return any headers that are requested. `authorization` is the only header listed in the OPTIONS Access-Control-Request-Headers request, so that's why it was the only one returned before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add endpoint to your server like `/api/ping`. When your app starts, send at first a request to the endpoint:

```
http.get('/api/ping');
```

without authentication, then consequent requests should work.

I haven't tried the solution, but may be it will help.

Comment: CORS works fine throughout the app for other posts. It's just specifically this one with the image attached.

Answer (score 0):

use native http functionality to avoid this
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/
it will work perferctally

Comment: I’m not using Cordova. This is a web app.

Comment: use jonp but i am not sure about this