# How Can I Solve this error for Mac Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, macos

In my jsp page I am using this ajax call for one button :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'some url',
  //url: $("#ssDHURL").val() + '/metaDataTests',
  data: {
      'type': metaTypeString,
      stringParam: metaIpStr,
  },
  traditional: true,
  dataType: 'html',
   success: function (response)
  {
  }
```

Above ajax call is working for all browser **but only not working for mac safar**i is their any help how to solve this problem?

In Mac-Pc Safari browser it showing error like:

> xmlHttprequest cannot load:some url: not allowed to request resource

Comment: Possibly dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari

Comment: are you using the same 'some url' for all the browsers and under the same situations? It looks for me to a session permissions issue, and probably you will have to send too the csrf token in order to indicate that the request comes from a specific session

Comment: @Jorge Yes I am using same url for all browser but it is only not working in safari browser....

Comment: Is it a cross-origin request maybe? Looks like Safari does not support wild card `*` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.