# Why am I receiving access control checks errors on safari?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mixed-content

I've gone through all the cors doc's on express.js guides and I seem to have everything setup perfectly, but I haven't been able to fix this issue on my production server. I don't get any errors on other browsers, only safari.

I've gone through other answer's on here [CORS request not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari) and haven't had any success. Note- the first message is a warning that I assume is has to with my api endpoint being served from a non secure page (http://api) and when I setup SSL (https://api) on it the message will go away

The error is:

```
[blocked] The page at https://website.com/login was not allowed to display insecure content from http://api.website.com/auth/login. 

Not allowed to request resource

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.website.com/auth/login due to access control checks.
```

This is just a standard ReactJs login form that sends a POST request like this:

```
axios.post(`${process.env.API}/auth/login`, params, { withCredentials: true })
.then(response => {
  ...
})
.catch(error => {
  ...
});
```

And here is my CORS setup in my api.

```
/index.js

const whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://website.com', 'https://website.com']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

app.use('/', routes(router));
```

I don't get any errors in development only on the production endpoint. Am I missing something?

Comment: The first message is not a warning. It’s a fatal error. It indicates the browser completely blocked the frontend code from accessing `http://api.website.com/auth/refresh`. The *“XMLHttpRequest cannot load”* message is just a side effect of the first error. So nothing in the question as currently written indicates any problem with the CORS configuration on the `http://api.website.com/auth/refresh` server. Instead it’s completely a mixed-content problem.

Comment: Interesting. It shows in the console as just a warning, but that would make sense. I'll go about adding SSL to my api and see if that works

Comment: Okay good catch @sideshowbarker I added SSL to my api which solved that insecure content issue and now it looks like everything is working as expected

Comment:  Cheers — glad to hear you got it working